# How can I make sure that a Kafka topic has been deleted?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Kafka's `Admin.deleteTopics` API unfortunately returns only after the request has been received - what only means that the topics are scheduled for deletion by the cluster, but not necessarily deleted *now*.

To show that as an example, the following code can often throw:

```
final var newTopic = new NewTopic("aaa", Optional.empty(), Optional.empty());
this.admin.createTopics(Collections.singleton(newTopic), opt).all().get();
this.admin.deleteTopics(Arrays.asList("aaa")).all().get();
this.admin.listTopics( ).names().get().contains("aaa"); // Returns 'false'.
this.admin.createTopics(Collections.singleton(newTopic), opt).all().get(); // <- throws
```

with an exception:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicExistsException: Topic 'aaa' is marked for deletion.
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:165)
...
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicExistsException: Topic 'aaa' is marked for deletion.
```

Unfortunately `Admin.listTopics()` that does not help here, the topic stops being visible after the delete request is submitted.

So the question is - is there any programatic way (preferably API) that would allow us to monitor that the topic is really gone?

Kafka (both client & server) version used is 3.2.

Comment: Ideally, you don't immediately create a topic after it is marked for deletion. I assume this is only for illustration purposes?

Comment: No, I have some internal tools process where I actually want to make sure the topic really gets deleted and re-created with the same name. If that was RabbitMQ I would not have this problem haha.

Comment: I'm not familiar with RabbitMQ, but I assume it is not distributed in a way like Kafka such that it needs to coordinate deletes across multiple servers. In Kafka case, all brokers with a replica need removed, then also all related Zookeeper entries, to fully remove the topic information. The Kafka response from the delete action is immediate (think: HTTP status 202), but the action itself on the cluster is not

Answer (score 1):

So far I have not found anything interesting in API, but I have some possible ideas, unfortunately all of them are ugly.

1. Each topic appears to have multiple metrics-beans related to their size, such as `kafka.log:type=Log,name=LogStartOffset,topic=aaa,partition=0`. So we could wait until they disappear. However to be fully sure we might need to check all brokers (or at least: all the replica-hosting ones).
2. A broker instance appears to have a bean named `kafka.controller:type=KafkaController,name=TopicsToDeleteCount` what might be what we want, however without fine-grained control. And we still might need to check all brokers in a cluster and wait until all of them reach 0.
3. Take a look into internal Zookeeper / KRaft structures. The interesting parts might be present at paths such as `/brokers/topics` and `/admin/delete_topics`, however this means bringing another (Zookeeper) dependency. KRaft is a similar case, we would be digging in brokers' internals.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `foo` topic after delete your topics, this maybe speed up Kafka Deletion. And then create the useful topics.
My test found that there is a certain effect.

```java
public void reCreateTopics(Set<String> topics) {
    adminClient.deleteTopics(topics).all().get();
    createFooTopic4TriggeringDelete();

    // may be sleep 1s before creating
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);

    adminClient.createTopics(topics).all().get();
}


private void createFooTopic4TriggeringDelete()  {
    NewTopic foo = new NewTopic("foo_" + System.currentTimeMillis(), 1, (short) 1);
    adminClient.createTopics(Collections.singleton(foo)).all().get();
    adminClient.deleteTopics(Collections.singleton(foo.name())).all().get();
}
```